# Correlated subqueries in MySql - how to evaluate outer query first?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery

I am having problems with subqueries in MySql. I have a table containing user groups. The columns are id, name and the properties with a comment describing each row:
(Id is INT, Name VARCHAR, all other TINYINT(1) (boolean that is)

```
ID   |   Name   |   login   |   post   |   manage
 1     user           1           0           0
 2     poster         1           1           0
 3     admin          1           1           1
```

My goal is to be able to list the usergroup properties (login, post and manage above) and the number of usergroups that has each property (3, 2 and 1 respectively).

This query works (but obviously counts the login column every time):

```
SELECT @colname:=cols.column_name,cols.column_comment,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.usergroups WHERE login=1) AS num_users
FROM information_schema.columns AS cols 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db' AND TABLE_NAME='usergroups' AND column_type='tinyint(1)';
```

This does not work (num_users is always 0)

```
SELECT @colname:=cols.column_name,cols.column_comment,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.usergroups WHERE cols.column_name=1) AS num_users
FROM information_schema.columns AS cols 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db' AND TABLE_NAME='usergroups' AND column_type='tinyint(1)';
```

This neither (num_users is always 0)

```
SELECT @colname:=cols.column_name,cols.column_comment,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.usergroups WHERE @colname=1) AS num_users
FROM information_schema.columns AS cols 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='db' AND TABLE_NAME='usergroups' AND column_type='tinyint(1)';
```

Is there any way to get this to work? That is - to evaluate the outer statement first?

-

Thanks a lot for any help!

/Victor

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this may do what you need:

```
select
  sum(login) as Num_Login_Groups,
  sum(post) as Num_Post_Groups,
  sum(manage) as Num_Manage_Groups
from db.usergroups;
```

Alternatively, if you really need 'login', 'post' and 'manage' to appear on the same row as the number of groups with that privilege, you could do this:

```
select 'login' as Property, sum(login) as Count from db.usergroups
union
select 'post' as Property, sum(post) as Count from db.usergroups
union
select 'manage' as Property, sum(manage) as Count from db.usergroups;
```

I'm assuming these are the only three properties your table will have.  If you want an extensible set of privileges for each user group, I would suggest storing them in a separate table, with one row for each applicable user-privilege pairing.

You might also consider using `Name` as the primary key of the table, as it is more intuitive and probably needs to be unique anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but counting the rows is not really the problem - the problem is that i have to (?) fetch the comment from information_schema (which is used as description or "pretty name") and in the same query want the count added. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That is really not the way to use a relational database. You *could* probably do it using prepared statements...

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.usergroups WHERE ' + col_name + '=1';
-- Execute statement etc...
```

But the real way to do this dynamically is to separate the columns into rows (i.e. have another table called `db.permissiontypes` or whatnot, then join it with `db.usergroups`.)

Comment: "That is really not the way ..." - Well... I would normally agree to this (and make an extra table as you suggest), especially since that gives you the possibility to add more info than just the column name and column comment. BUT in this case (as name and description is all that is needed) putting them as columns means that i can omit one join and thus speed up normal operation a little bit.

With the "better" way I would have to do "usertable JOIN usergroups JOIN usergroupproperties", now "usertable JOIN usergroups" is enough.

And.. The boss asked for it! ;-)

Comment: Hmmm... Well I can't argue if the structure is set in stone and unchangeable, but as far as performance goes, you won't get better performance in a relational database by solving it in a non-relational way. Not in this case anyways. Having another table will definitely be faster than dynamic SQL thanks to internal optimizations.

Comment: Hmm... That sounds really strange to me... Are you sure? I men - of course the kind of query we are discussing here will be quite slow, but normally (when not accessing the admin page basically) the only info needed is user + group + group properties (which means a join of two tables, one row from each table). Otherwise the result is has to be joined from three tables (fetching one row from each). Sure, the difference might not be big, but it cant be quicker with 3 tables, right?

Also - in the latter case - does foreign keys has to be specified explicitly to get the performance advantage?